# Blogger not redirecting

Tags: redirects, domains, blogger

I bought a new domain [staygeo.com](http://staygeo.com) and pointed my blogger blog to [gis.staygeo.com](http://gis.staygeo.com). I have checked the box in blogger publishing settings saying *Redirect staygeo.com to gis.staygeo.com*. Still if I just type http://staygeo.com/, I see **Not Found** message. What can be done about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed these instructions http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1233381 and changed the CNAME for your domain?

Comment: But you want the top level domain to redirect, so you need to do that as well.

Comment: Sorry paulmorriss, I deleted my old comment without refreshing the page! So saw your comment later. Now I followed the instructions to **On a top-level domain (www.example.com).**. Google writes *A-records (optional)
The following action links your naked domain (example.com) to your actual site (www.example.com). If you skip this step, visitors who leave off the "www" will see an error page.*, but if I add **www** I see **Not Found** error. Otherwise the redirection works fine - http://staygeo.com now redirects to http://gis.staygeo.com!

Comment: Google tell you how to put your blog at www.example.com and how to redirect people from example.com to www.example.com. You've followed their instructions but instead of using www you've used gis. However you can't now redirect www as well, using their instructions. You'll have to put a redirect using your domain settings from www.staygeo.com to gis.staygeo.com.